# Field/class name collision in Java

Tags: java

I've got a field of type T named (sorry) T. T has a static method M. I am trying to call T's static method T.M(), but compiler thinks I am referencing the field, not the class and fails with the error "non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context". Is there any way I can excplicitly specify that I want the class, not the variable, aside from renaming it?

```
class A
{
    T T;
    static void X() { T.M(); }
}

class T
{
    static public void M() { }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the compiler rules are, but you are looking for trouble! Moreover, unless this is allowed in java 8 (I haven't used it quite enough), you can't call a static method of a template parameter.

Comment: What's keeping you from renaming it? You should use at least `T t` although a more descriptive name should be considered over that.

Comment: Pshemo: that method should be static, sorry, edited again

Comment: Pshemo, this is not one of these "why I can't access non-static from static" questions, the variable A.T only became relevant because of the name confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should just rename the variable.

If your type is in a package, use Diego's answer.

If you really really don't want to rename the variable and your class isn't in a package, you can do this abominable thing with reflection:

```
Class classT = T.class;
Method staticMethod = classT.getMethod("M", null);
staticMethod.invoke(null);
```

Answer (score 4):

Given that your classes are inside a package, prepend the package's name to your T class name to form the [FQCN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name):

```java
package com.stackoverflow;


class A
{
    T T;
    void X() { com.stackoverflow.T.M(); }
}

class T
{
    static public void M() { }
}
```

**Another solution, using reflection**

```java
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

class A
{
    T T;
    void X() {
        try {
            com.stackoverflow.T.class.getDeclaredMethod("M").invoke(null, null);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class T
{
    static public void M() {
        System.out.println("M");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Class.forName("T")` - that gets you a class object with name T.

Comment: If `T` is a generic parameter, that will never work!

Comment: I don't see any mention that T is a type parameter

Comment: @GiovanniBotta no, you are wrong, it is not generic in OP example

Comment: You should explain how you propose to call method M of T.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add one option:

```
Class.forName( "T" ).getMethod( "M" ).invoke( null );
```

This will work if the class name is just "T" - no package.

Comment: Class `T` has no method `T`. You probably want to use `getMethod( "M" )` there.

Comment: Pshemo: please re-read the question. I am not trying to acces A.T at all. I need the static method T.M(), but Java thinks otherwise because A has a variable with the same name.

Comment: @NK22 OK, my bad. Sorry for confusion. Will remove my comments. In that case using full-package-name of class should be preferred solution.